# Postgres reindex index concurrently not finishing

Tags: postgresql

I have a strange behavior on my postgres server version 13.
The index is very small. When I run:

```
reindex index my_index_name;
```

It is very fast. But when I try

```
reindex index concurrently my_index_name;
```

It won't finish. It runs for days. There are not lock on the server, nothing. What can be the problem here?

Comment: What is the `state` of the corresponding session in `pg_stat_activity`. And what does `pg_stat_progress_create_index` show?

Comment: State is active.
pg_stat_pogress_create_index:
pid                | 68861
datid              | 16465
datname            | mydatname
relid              | 16551
index_relid        | 701481
command            | REINDEX CONCURRENTLY
phase              | waiting for old snapshots
lockers_total      | 2
lockers_done       | 1
current_locker_pid | 12050
blocks_total       | 4
blocks_done        | 0
tuples_total       | 0
tuples_done        | 0
partitions_total   | 0
partitions_done    | 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem:
There were many open connections with the stat Idle in transaction.

This connections prevented the reindex to start. It was always in the phase waiting for old snapshot (seen with select * from pg_stat_progress_create_index;
)

I restarted the postgres server, now everything works fine.